# count(for in range) TypeError Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting the following error

```
'TypeError: must be str, not generator'.
```

for the code below

```
a = '0123456789 01234 01234567890 6789012345 012322456789'
b = a.split(" ")
for num in b:
    if num.count(**i for i in range(10)**) <= 1:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

This above should check whether each number has any duplicated number (`False`) or not (`True`).

For instance, the first number `0123456789` returns `True` because it doesn't have any duplicated number.

On the other hand, the last number `012322456789` returns `False` because it has three of '2'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `.count()` with multiple arguments. Change your condition to:

```
if all(num.count(str(i)) <= 1 for i in range(10)):
```

This will test each digit against the string and return True if `all` of them are repeated 1 or 0 times.

You can also only test for the digits in `num` instead of using every digit from `0` to `9`:

```
if all(num.count(i) == 1 for i in num):
```

or use `set` to test for uniqueness:

```
if len(set(num)) == len(num):
```